# If Bitcoin hits $100,000 how much is 0.01 Bitcoin worth in $?

Tags: divisibility

Just trying to figure out and calculate how much 0.01 Bitcoin would cost in $ if 1 Bitcoin hits $100,000.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is basic math and unrelated to cryptocurrencies.

Comment: While I see your point. I guess if people ask such a question others might search for it and SE has a good visability with search engines thus I will answer it now.

Answer (score 1):

First of all 0.01 Bitcoin is 0.01 Bitcoin which is one hundredth of a Bitcoin.

So if people would be willing to pay $100,000 for one Bitcoin naive economy and math would suggest that they are willing to pay one hundredth of that amount for one hundredth of a Bitcoin which is $1,000.